# invalid read of size 4 when using free()

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind, free

I'm new with C and valgrind and trying to learn them.
When I use following function:

```
void die(const char *message,struct Connection *conn){
    if (conn){
        free(conn->file);
        free(conn->db);
        free(conn);
    }
    if (errno){
        perror(message);
    }else{
        printf("ERROR:$s\n",message);
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

to print errors and free memory from structs (here is their declaration):

```
struct Address{
    int id;
    int set;
    char name[MAX_DATA];
    char email[MAX_DATA];
};

struct Database{
    struct Address rows[MAX_ROWS];
};

struct Connection{
    FILE *file;
    struct Database *db;
};
```

i got errors like these from valgrind:

```
==15471== 2 errors in context 61 of 62
==15471== Invalid read of size 4
==15471==     at 0x4EA5889: _IO_default_setbuf (genops.c:567)
==15471==     by 0x4EA4928: _IO_file_setbuf@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:454)
==15471==     by 0x4EA6C32: _IO_unbuffer_write (genops.c:979)
==15471==     by 0x4EA6C32: _IO_cleanup (genops.c:1019)
==15471==     by 0x4E67F14: exit (exit.c:100)
==15471==     by 0x40097F: die (ex17.c:33)
==15471==     by 0x400DF4: Database_get (ex17.c:105)
==15471==     by 0x40102F: main (ex17.c:139)
==15471== Addres 0x51d53f0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 568 free'd
==15471==     at 0x4C2845A: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:473)
==15471==     by 0x40091D: die (ex17.c:25)
==15471==     by 0x400DF4: Database_get (ex17.c:105)
==15471==    by 0x40102F: main (ex17.c:139)
```

but when executing wihout valgrind i don't have memory errors.
Can it be caused by passing `NULL` to `free()`? And is it really an error, cause man says that `free(NULL)` just do nothing?

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Do not try to make C look like Python (and vice-versa). Put the closing braces at the same indentation level as the **line** of the opening!

Comment: Did you actually close the file? Looks as if after program termination there is a file to be closed. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: FWIW, `free(NULL);` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't `free` a `FILE *` pointer, as you don't `malloc` it either. You pass a `FILE *` pointer to `fclose()` which will destroy it for you (and also free memory, if such memory does exist - as it is nowhere defined that a `FILE *` pointer points to memory that has been allocated by `malloc` and only in such a case calling `free` on it would be legal).

Also you don't show how you allocate all that memory. When you allocate `conn` using just `malloc()` and don't explicitly allocate `conn->db` or set it to `NULL`, its value is undefined (`malloc` returns basically memory filled with "random bytes"), so after `malloc` the values of `conn->db` might be `NULL` (if you are lucky because very often memory is zero filled) or it may be something else. You always need to allocate using `calloc` if you want to be sure that all allocated memory is zeroed (and thus all booleans are false, all integer values are 0 and all pointers are `NULL`).

Answer (score 4):

There is no situation I'm aware of where `free`ing a `FILE` pointer is legal if you are not libc, which you aren't. Whatever you intend `free(conn->file);` to mean, that is definitely not the way to do it.

What happens is that you freed some memory that wasn't yours to free and on exit libc does its own clean up of open files and that crashes because it touches memory you've ruined for it.

If I have to guess, you probably meant `fclose` there.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: It looks to me like a very classic problem. Maybe you or the application tries to access a memory address which has been freed before. This can cause a crash.

But for your specific case:
A File pointer should not be freed. Instead you should close the file with the appropriate Ansi C function and set the pointer to NULL again.

Question: Is your application multi threaded?

Because it is possible that someone tries to access a pointer (another thread) after you freed it.